# How to solve Exception during editing information into Struts2 jQuery Grid

Tags: java, jqgrid, struts2

How to solve Exception during editing information into Struts2 jQuery Grid
Using Struts2 jQuery Grid, when I tried to edit the existing entry, I am getting exceptions. But I can create new entity. The exception is created only the edit time. The exception is like the following:

Note: I tried to edit based on the userID column value. So, I passed that into DAO as String and I converted that to integer to select the entity.

JSP error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:417)
    java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
    com.bookapp.template.UsersDAO.getUserByID(UsersDAO.java:108)
    com.bookapp.template.TestActionJSON.changeData(TestActionJSON.java:161)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    .....
```

Struts2 jQuery grid code:

```
<sjg:grid id="gridtable1" editurl="%{editurl}" editinline="true".....>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="userID" index="userID" title="userID"
        sortable="true" editable="false" key="true"/>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="userName" index="userName" title="userName"
        sortable="true" editable="true" />
</sjg:grid>
```

The Action java code:

```
public class ActionJSON ....{
    private String oper;
    private String userName;
    private String userID;

    public String changeData() {
        if (oper.equalsIgnoreCase("edit")) {
            UsersDAO dao = new UsersDAO();
            Users editUser = dao.getUserByID(userID);
            editUser.setUserName(userName);
            dao.updateUser(editUser);
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

DAO implementation:

```
public Users getUserByID(String userID) {
    .....
    int longId = Integer.parseInt(userID);
    Users entry = (Users) s.get(Users.class, longId);
    .....
    return entry;
}

public void updateUser(Users entry) {
    ...
    s.saveOrUpdate(entry);
    ....
}
```

And struts2 code is:

```
<action name="changeData" class="com.bookapp.template.ActionJSON" method="changeData">
        <result type="json" />
        <result name="error" type="json" />
</action>
```

Which thing actually creating  the problem / exception and how to solve that, can you please tell me?

Comment: Apart from the actual problem, I strongly suggest you to avoid stuff like `int longId` or `Users user`... if it's int, call it int; to represent a user, call the object User, and call users a list of User object...

Comment: I modified the code and i define as int. But now, I am getting exception of "java.lang.NullPointerException". I implemented the same logic for simple jsp pages without grid. But when I tried to use grid, I am getting this exception.

Comment: I was meaning that as a rule of common sense for the future, to follow conventions and avoid bad practices... naming is not related to your actual problem, it is just *another* problem

Comment: I finally solved the problem. The problem was only the type casting. Now, I changed the code into plain data type and it works fully. Thanks for your suggestion.